# Modify DOM element loaded asynchronously

Tags: javascript, dom

I'd like to change DOM element but for the asynchronously DOM element javascript doesn't seem able to see it

https://jsfiddle.net/Scippy/xf3swycn/3/

```js
function myTestFunction() {
    const str = document.getElementById("animation");
    var x = str.getElementsByTagName("g");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        var res = x[i].innerHTML.replace("rgb(41,37,127)", "#21A73F");     
        x[i].innerHTML = res;
    }

}
```

```html
<button onclick="myTestFunction()">Change Fill Color</button>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js"></script>
<lottie-player src="https://assets3.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_0gfEPCHLKZ.json" background="transparent" speed="1" loop="" autoplay=""></lottie-player>
```

Comment: It's not because it was "loaded" asynchronously, but because it is encapsulated in a Shadow DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `animation` element is housed within a shadow DOM so its elements sit in a separate DOM. To access the elements within that you can use [`.shadowRoot`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/shadowRoot) to obtain the [shadow root object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot) representation of your shadow dom. Once you have this, you can query for all elements with the `fill` attribute set to the `rgb` value you want to change, and then loop through each and update the `fill` attribute to your new colour. Do not use `.innerHTML`, as this will create new `svg` elements that your lottie player isn't able to correctly reference stopping the animation from working.

Having said that, I would check the lottie docs to ensure that this is the recommended way to go about programmatically changing the colour of your lottie animations and that an existing API or method doesn't already exist.

See example below:

```js
function myTestFunction() {
  const shadowRoot = document.getElementById("player").shadowRoot;
  shadowRoot.querySelectorAll("#animation [fill='rgb(41,37,127)']").forEach(svg => {
    svg.setAttribute("fill", "#21A73F");
  });
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myTestFunction()">Change Fill Color</button>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js"></script>
<lottie-player src="https://assets3.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_0gfEPCHLKZ.json" background="transparent" id="player" speed="1" loop="" autoplay=""></lottie-player>
```

Comment: Great! And is there any way to make it automatically on the page load?

Comment: I've tried with observer but it don't work

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Scippy/xf3swycn/19/

Comment: @scippy Your code looks like it works to me. But it's probably easiest to listen to when the animation data has loaded and then style it by using an event listener and listening to the [ready](https://lottiefiles.github.io/lottie-player/events.html) event like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/2bvqad1k/)

Comment: You're definitely the Master chief!